# How to pass image as prop to custom component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a custom component and flatlist in the search screen, I'm trying to load each result in the custom component. Data inside the flatlist is an array of objects which is a response from API. When I pass image, name and other details to the custom component to display on the card only the style loads up with no data on it.

Here is my code

Card.js:

```
    const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>

                    <View>
                        <Image
                            source = {{uri : props.source}}
                            style={{ borderRadius: 100, width: 80, height: 80, margin: 10 }}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ marginLeft: 15, margin: 10 }}>
                        <Text>{props.name}</Text>
                        {/* <Text>{props.cuisine}</Text>
                        <Text>{props.cost}</Text> */}
                    </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Main.js:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    keyExtractor={(x, i) => x + i}
    renderItem={({ item }) => 
              <Card 
                 source = {item.thumb} 
                 name = {item.name}    
              />
     }
/>
```

An image just to be more clear

[image]

Comment: Try to `console.log` the `item.thumb`. It might be a relative URL which works on the web but unfortunately not on RN.

Comment: why I'm not getting name then?

Comment: Well are both of those properties present inside the items in your state?

Comment: could you share your ```this.state.data```.

Comment: Hey, both of you guys thanks I wasn't thinking I guess, got the data it was inside another object.

Comment: Why don't you answer it I will mark it as answered.

Comment: @user12551649 do you able to make it work?

Comment: Yes, When I logged the data to give it to you and I realized it was inside another object thus throwing an undefined error.

Comment: @user12551649 I’m glad you found a solution.